# How to display listbox with items such as item.name is shown in the list while the value passed is item.id?

Tags: c#, listbox

Upon selecting any item from the list, I want some other property to be passed than the one already being displayed.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you have to fill your `LitBox` items. You have two options here:

1 - By adding items

```
listBox.Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<Object, String>("Key", "Text"));
```

2 - By binding to a data source

```
listBox.DataSource = objectDataSource;
listBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
listBox.ValueMember = "ID";
```

Now, to get the selected item you can do the following:

```
KeyValuePair<Object, String> listBoxItem = 
    (KeyValuePair<Object, String>listBox.SelectedItem;
String text = listBoxItem.Value.ToString();
Object key = listBoxItem.Key;
```

---

Refer to :

[ListBox Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx)

[KeyValuePair Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Set listbox `DataSource` to your data source

Set listbox  `ValueMember` to the `"Id"`

Set listbox  `DisplayMember` to the value you want displayed, i.e. `"Name"`.